# phpMyAdmin and node.js

Tags: php, mysql, sql, node.js

I have created aa database called users in phpmyadmin and a table called personalinformation. I can connect to the database just fine using node.js javascript with this code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "user",
password: "****",
database: "users",

});

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");

});
```

the table is already populated with some data. I now want to add extra data into the table. I used this code but its telling me that the table doesnt exist

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "user",
password: "password",
database: "users",


});

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");

var sql = "INSERT INTO personalinformation (title, firstname, surname, mobile, email) VALUES ?";
var values = [
    ['Mr', 'John', 'Whelan', '0868337', 'john@gmail.com'],
    ['Mr', 'Peter', 'Lawless', '0885947', 'peter@gmail.com'],
    ['Ms', 'Amy', 'Apple', '08736855', 'amy@gmail.com']

];
con.query(sql, [values], function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
});

});
```

the table structure is like this:

```
title     firstname      surname     mobile           email
 mr        john           whelan     0976577567      john@home.com
```

etc and there error message is Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'users.personalinformation' doesn't exist

My database is called users and the table is called personalinformation so im confused as to why its saying it doesnt exist

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i edited the post there

Comment: I don't know that specific driver/database combination, but sometimes you'll get a table doesn't exist error message if the user doesn't have permission to the table/view/schema. Can you confirm permissions for that specific user?

Comment: No, I meant the actual structure, via a db dump/export

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have **more than one drive**, and the settings must be provided with the ***port*** of the mysql

Comment: This answer could be improved with a code example of what you are suggesting

Comment: var sql = "SHOW TABLES";
con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});

please run this code and give me the answers